# Why did Tom agree to go on the alien ship?

Tags: falling-skies

End of season 1, which created a cliffhanger and a future subplot.

The reason that was given: Come or we call Ben. How could he believe this threat? If they had the capability, then they would have done it already.
Perhaps to find a cure for Ben? Why would they help him. I can't see any positive scenario here.

Comment: Don't you expect to find out in Season 2?

Comment: You mean, they would compensate and provide an explanation for his state of mind at that time to make such a poor decision? I've watched the first two episodes of season 2 to be safe; there's no news.